# How to remove a class in a Jquery button event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remove from 2 buttons events a class.
What I want to achieve is that when I press the button the class 'success' will be removed.
I tried to do so in the next 2 buttons:

```
// Button handlers
    $('#study_acrf').click(function() {
        _this.start();
        $('#soa_table').removeClass('success'); //success
    });

    $('#export_acrf').click(function() {
        $('#table_data').val($("<div />")
            .append($("#soa_table").clone()).html());
        $('#preview_form').submit();
        window.open('/study_versions/' + studyVersionId + '/export?study_version[export_type]=acrf');
    });
```

In this what happening is that on button pressing I'm showing a view where there is a table. This table is cloned from another view where you can select one column and that is the class 'success'. This class makes the cell header of the columns green and I want to rid off it when the table is in the new view. I tried various stuff but I have no idea how to solve this issue. In the screenshot shared you can see the table with those greens which I don't want to see anymore. 
 [image: Screenshot of my problem]

The HTML of the table where this happening:

```
<table id="soa_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed soa-table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>SoA</th>
        <th id="6" class="soa-column text-center">V1</th>
        <th id="102" class="soa-column text-center success">V2</th>
        <th id="103" class="soa-column text-center">V3</th>
        <th id="104" class="soa-column text-center">V4</th>
        <th id="105" class="soa-column text-center">V5</th>
        <th id="106" class="soa-column text-center">V6</th>
        <th id="107" class="soa-column text-center">V7</th>
        <th id="108" class="soa-column text-center">V8</th>
        <th id="109" class="soa-column text-center">V9</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="soa-row" id="2">Demographics (Pilot)</td>
        <td class="soa-element text-center" form_id="2" visit_id="6" id="18">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success"></span>
        </td>
        <td class="soa-element" form_id="2" visit_id="102" id="0">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="soa-element text-center" form_id="2" visit_id="103" id="21">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success"></span>
        </td>
        <td class="soa-element" form_id="2" visit_id="104" id="0">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="soa-element" form_id="2" visit_id="105" id="0">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="soa-element" form_id="2" visit_id="106" id="0">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="soa-element" form_id="2" visit_id="107" id="0">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="soa-element" form_id="2" visit_id="108" id="0">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="soa-element" form_id="2" visit_id="109" id="0">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="soa-row success" id="6">Education (Pilot)</td>
        <td class="soa-element" form_id="6" visit_id="6" id="0">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="soa-element text-center" form_id="6" visit_id="102" id="25">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success"></span>
        </td>
        <td class="soa-element" form_id="6" visit_id="103" id="0">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="soa-element" form_id="6" visit_id="104" id="0">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="soa-element text-center" form_id="6" visit_id="105" id="24">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success"></span>
        </td>
        <td class="soa-element" form_id="6" visit_id="106" id="0">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="soa-element" form_id="6" visit_id="107" id="0">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="soa-element" form_id="6" visit_id="108" id="0">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="soa-element" form_id="6" visit_id="109" id="0">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: `removeClass()` is exactly how you would remove a class.  Perhaps you're selecting the wrong element?  We can't know, because we can't see your HTML.

Comment: `I tried to do so in the next 2 buttons:`-> my question is are your buttons are generated dynamically? Also are they have same id `study_acrf`?

Comment: I added the HTML view of the table

Comment: I fixed doing this: `$('#soa_table thead tr th, #soa_table tbody tr td').removeClass('success');` This get rid off of the green don't know if best solution but worked for me actually

Comment: The buttons are in the HTML and the Jquery handle the action.
One button called: `#study_acrf`and Second Button `#export_acrf`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my own issues just adding more selection to the tag like this:

```
$('#soa_table thead tr th, #soa_table tbody tr td').removeClass('success');
```